# How to trim zeros after decimal point

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to trim zeros after a decimal point as below but it's not giving desired result.

```
trig = [currentVal doubleValue];
trig = trig/100;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
display.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:trig]];
```

The number is still being displayed without trimming zeros after the decimal point.

Here `currentVal` is the number I am entering.

For example if i pass  "trig" = 123 (Initially "trig" = 123 after doing trig/100 i want to display 1.23 but it is displaying as 1.23000000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-BCIFDDIB), it looks like `setFractionDigits:` is only for converting the other way.

The best thing to do is probably to convert your number to an integer before formatting it e.g.

```
 double converted = round(trig); // man round for docs
```

You can use also the formatting functions of `stringWithFormat:` of `NSString`, but then you will lose all the localisation advantages you get with `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 31):

Sometimes the straight C format specifiers do an easier job than the Cocoa formatter classes, and they can be used in the format string for the normal `stringWithFormat:` message to `NSString`.

If your requirement is to not show any trailing zeroes, then the "g" format specifier does the job:

```
float y = 1234.56789f;

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", y];
```

Notice that there is no precision information, which means that the `printf` library will remove the trailing zeroes itself.

There is more information in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), which refer to IEEE's [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: Thank you but if g = 123.2314100000 in such case i  want to display g as 123.23141

Comment: It works fine but it gives Exponential form for large numbers & i don't want that.. Any solution to that?

Answer (score 4):

In case this helps someone. I wanted 1 decimal value but no '.0' on the end if the float was '1.0'. Using %g would give scientific notation for longer numbers, following ugliness worked well enough for me as high accuracy wasn't critical.

```
// Convert to 1 dp string,
NSString* dirtyString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.1f", self.myFloat];

// Convert back to float that is now a maximum of 1 dp,
float myDirtyFloat = [dirtyString floatValue];

// Output the float subtracting the zeros the previous step attached
return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%g", myDirtyFloat];
```

Answer (score 3):

This will not display any decimal value after the decimal point:

```
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", trig];
```

This will just trim the zeros after the decimal point:

```
isplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.2f", trig];
display.text = [display.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat@"0"]]];
```

Note, this may leave you with the trailing decimal point. "124." may happen. I guess that some smarter solution will be posted soon.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a proper solution where there is `NSNumberFormetter` Class, But I just did this rather then googling a lot! ;)

Here is an example, if it helps:

```
-(NSString*) trimZerosAfterDecimalPoint:(NSString*)string_ {

    double doubleValue=[string_ doubleValue];    
    long   leftPart=(long)doubleValue;
    double rightPart=doubleValue-(double)leftPart;

    NSString *rightPartAsStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", rightPart];

    int i=0;
    for (i=rightPartAsStr.length-1; i>=2; i--) {
        if ([rightPartAsStr characterAtIndex:i]!='0') {            
            rightPartAsStr=[rightPartAsStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, i-1)];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i<2) {
        string_=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", leftPart];
    } else {
        string_=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.%@", leftPart, rightPartAsStr];
    }

    return string_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this for one of my programs and heres how I went about it:

```
- (void) simplify{
        int length = (int)[self.calcString length];
        for (int i = (int)[self.calcString length]; i > 0; i--) {
            if  ([self.calcString rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) {
                NSRange prevChar = NSMakeRange(i-1, 1);
                if ([[self.calcString substringWithRange:prevChar] isEqualToString:@"0"]||
                    [[self.calcString substringWithRange:prevChar] isEqualToString:@"."]) 
                    length--;
                else
                    break;
        }
        self.calcString = [self.calcString substringToIndex:length];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
display.text = [@(trig) stringValue];
```

Comment: Maybe you should add an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of your datatype cannot be formatted is such a manner.